# Configure NLB for IIS Websites

Tags: iis-8

We have two IIS Servers SERVER A and Server B, where my website (port80) is hosted. I have configured a NLB CLuster for this website using fortinet firewall. and all the links which are pointed to cluster IP.

Health monitor for NLB is configured as 
1. Check port 80 is up or not

Problem is:
Suppose my website is running in Server A. when i stopped the IIS in Server A, the website is not failovering to sever B, because port 80 is still open.

But if i disable the network connection in server A, failover will work and the website is accessible though server B.

I need to configure the NLB as, whenever my IIS goes down, failover should happen. Can any one should guide me which port/Service that i need to check in the NLB health monitoring. Appreciate any response

Answer (score 0):

Look if you have "Default web site" up and running on port 80 in your IIS. If so, either stop/delete it or reconfigure your health check.